# Getting a list of x coordinates of intersection points of two functions

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, intersection

I have two functions,

```
f[x_] := 5 Sin[2 x] 
g[x_] := (5 x + 2)/(x + 2)
```

I am trying to find the `x` coordinates that intersect between these two functions. I am new to Mathematica and everything I have tried isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @Tdogg What have you tried so far? In what ways have your attempts failed?

Answer (score 8):

Your function `f[x]` is bounded to the interval $[-5, 5]$. On the other hand, $g[x] > 5$ for $x < -2$, so they never intersect there.

For $x>-2$, your functions intersect at infinitely many points. You can convince yourself of this by plotting them together using your definition:

```
Plot[
  {Legended[f[x], "f(x)"], Legended[g[x], "g(x)"]},
  {x, -2, 20}, Exclusions -> {x == -2},
  PlotRange -> {-7, 6}
]
```

[image: Functions intersect at infinitely many points]

Finding a closed form representing them all may be a major undertaking, if one exists at all.

On the other hand, **numerical solutions** can be obtained for any one of these intersections with a variety of techniques. For instance, the following finds the solution closest to 5:

```
FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 5}]

(* {x -> 4.2916} *)
```

More generally, you can find an arbitrary number of `x` values for which your equation holds using the `FindInstance` function:

```
FindInstance[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals, 10] // N

(*{
{x->69.7947},{x->500.259},{x->528.612},
{x->296.147},{x->299.185},{x->233.205},
{x->261.482},{x->443.708},{x->318.036},
{x->239.604}
} 
*)
```

Comment: Surely you meant to write `g[x] < -5` rather than `g[x] > 5`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I think I did actually mean `g[x]>5`. g[x] has a discontinuity at $x=-2$; on its other side, which is not shown in the plot, g[x] is always larger than 5. I will widen the plot range to make that point more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you restrict your interest to a finite range, say -2 <= x <= 20, you can use `NSolve` or `Solve`

```
f[x_] = 5 Sin[2 x];
g[x_] = (5 x + 2)/(x + 2);

soln = NSolve[{f[x] == g[x], -2 <= x <= 20}, x]
```

> {{x -> -1.10963}, {x -> 0.124782}, {x -> 1.30019}, {x -> 3.53708}, {x
>   -> 
>      4.2916}, {x -> 6.76161}, {x -> 7.36518}, {x -> 9.94844}, {x -> 
>      10.4663}, {x -> 13.1197}, {x -> 13.5804}, {x -> 16.2826}, {x -> 
>      16.7017}, {x -> 19.4406}, {x -> 19.8276}}

`Solve` will return `Root` objects which can be converted to values with `N`

```
soln == Solve[{f[x] == g[x], -2 <= x <= 20}, x] // N
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

`NSolve` and `FindRoot` as already shown are the most relevant.

Just for fun. Noting that for x>0, g[x] approaches 5 from below as x approaches infinity. This implies an infinite number of zeroes for f[x]-g[x]. Just looking at [-1.9,2] for visualization and extraction of approximations from plot:

```
plt = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1.9, 5}, Exclusions -> All, 
  MeshFunctions -> (f@#1 - g@#1 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]
ext = Union[
  Extract[plt[[1, 1]], List /@ Cases[plt, Point[x__] :> x, -1]][[1, 
    All, 1]], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.0001 &)]
```

[image]

The approximate roots: {-1.10963, 0.124784, 1.30019, 3.53708, 4.2916}.

Threshold for `SameTest` just a quick guess (modify as desired).

Comment: This is very cool! +1

Comment: @MarcoB thank you :)